# Is it possible to have separate SSH keys for separate users

Tags: ssh, user

So let's say I have 2 accounts, pi and cloud. I want to be able to let people access the cloud account(which doesn't have sudo permissions) but I don't want them to access the pi account(which has sudo permissions). Would it be possible for me to have separate keys for pi and and cloud?

Comment: SSH keys are always user specific so if you generate a key pair for each user account and place each in the `authorized_keys` you have what you want.

Comment: yes and if you use the environment parameter (and enable the feature) you can set environment variables up which are different depending on which key logged in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has the private and public key pairs for the host in `/etc/ssh`.
These are normally set when the OS is initially created.

`~/.ssh` holds the key pairs for the user, which can be different for each user and can hold multiple key pairs.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was like that but I thought it would overide my existing keys for the pi user

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion about how public and private keys work.

Your host (the Pi itsself) has a key-pair with which it is identified. You can see the public key in `~/.ssh/known_host`, although you you may not be able to make heads or tails of it.

When you log in, you use your own key-pair. A user on the Pi will have a file `.ssh/authorized_keys` in which the public keys of the remote users that are allowed to login to this pi-user are kept. Basically, `authorized_keys` is a concatenation of all the `id_rsa.pub`-s of the remote users that are granted access to that  Pi-user.

So, what you would probably do is:

- collect the `id_rsa.pub`-s of your users
- put those in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` of your user `cloud`
- collect the `id_rsa.pub`-s of your admins
- put those in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` of your user `pi`